# Google oauth javascript SDK not working in IE

Tags: javascript, oauth, sdk

The JavaScript SDK is working in all other browsers except IE. In IE its showing a warning message "The web page you are  viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close the window? "  and after user action its showing a blank page and the authentication fails.

Using IE 11. There is a "access denied" message in console and the response from sdk contains an error message, "popup closed by user"

Comment: A better question would be: "what does work in IE?"

Comment: 1) which version of IE - 2) are there any useful errors in the **developer** tools console and 3) does anyone still care about IE?

Comment: Can you provide some screen shots? And code snippets